# Responsive circle and image fit on circle

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to create a responsive circle and I want to fit the image. I want to use `img` tag not with css (background)

Here is what i've tried

```
.circular--portrait {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circular--portrait img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

<div class="circular--portrait">
                <img src="img.jpg" />
            </div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use background?

Comment: add border-radius: 50%; on image

Comment: what is the issue? your code works

Comment: it's not responsive:(

Comment: Then use `background` - it solves that, and a bunch more, issues that are more difficult to solve when using a standard `img` tag.

Comment: I want to be scalable

Comment: @Adam I can't use background because i'm using handlebars for frontend..the image will be dinamically

Comment: @Geor1947 - I thought you were going to say that - just use an inline style - `<div class="circuluar--portrait" style="background-image: url(...)">`

Comment: make `.circular-portrait img` `height: 100%` so as to shrink with parent `div` on screen resize

Comment: @Adam and in the inline I can do something like .. 'style="background-image:url({{myImage}})">' ?

Comment: @Geor1947 - of course. Why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
.circular--portrait {
  position: relative;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.circular--portrait img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="circular--portrait">
  <img src="http://beerhold.it/500/300" />
</div>
```

Comment: It's a nice solution but image it's not looking perfect good.. width or height is bigger..

Comment: u can change this

Comment: @Geor1947 sorry I did not immediately understand what you mean. fixed

Comment: thanks a lot! that's what I want. I have a question what is vw? It's good to use vw than em or percent?

Comment: @Geor1947 "vw" - 1/100th of the width of the viewport. "vh" -  1/100th of the height of the viewport.

Comment: thanks.But if the image is on desktop too large and on mobile is to little? Better to user something else?

Comment: @Geor1947 - you can use `object-fit: scale-down` which would prevent it from stretching. Howeverm it's also worth pointing out that this CSS property has **no IE support**. Keep in mind it's also **your responsibility** to set the correct container size, most likely using media queries, so that it doesn't get too big or too little. The OP simply provided an example.

Comment: @Adam not in this case..maybe on another

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that has the image be responsive according to the width of its parent container.

```css
.container {
  /* Feel free to adjust the values here so you can see it being responsive */
  width: 200px;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 100% 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/Chapultepec_Zoo_-_Jaguar_%2802%29.jpg/2560px-Chapultepec_Zoo_-_Jaguar_%2802%29.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try it out on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/baohouse/pen/xaEVxB)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with SCSS. You just need to create one variable.

```css
$width: calc(100vw / 5);
.circle {
  width: $width;
  height: $width;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350');
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

[please see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mangesh1556/ztv8okgo/24/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with SCSS. You just need to create one variable.

```css
$width: calc(100vw / 5);
.circle {
  width: $width;
  height: $width;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">
</div>
<div class="circle">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="">
</div>
```

[Please see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mangesh1556/ztv8okgo/27/)